# Function works one time only - C

Tags: c, list, function, hyperlink, linked-list

Thank you all for the feedback! 
Here is the solution after applying the fixes.

```
typedef struct employeeData
{
    //....
    char* Name[20]; //Char name needed to be defined size. Or use of Malloc in the functions
    //...
} employee;
```

Issue where add before head was returning a crash...

```
if (addEMP_ID < head->EMP_ID)
    {
        current->next = head;
        head =  current; //Required for this scenario
        return current;
    }
```

Comment: Accept one of the answers which fixed your problem.

Comment: they both did though. I had 2 problems and they each fixed one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue you have is your `employeeData` structure.
The Name member is defined as a pointer (i.e. no space is allocated, just a pointer to where memory is allocated), and yet you are populating it in your `add()` function via a `strcpy()`.

You have two choices, either change the structure's definition of Name, to have a fixed size (like `char Name[20];`), or use a `malloc()` to allocate space in your `add()` function, and then strcpy().  For example:

```
current->Name = malloc(strlen(addName)+1);    
strcpy(current->Name, addName);
```

You will of course have to issue a `free()` of the Name member in your `delete()` function.

Answer (score 1):

First, sorry for my bad english.

I notice some problem,
here

```
if (addEMP_ID < head->EMP_ID)
{
    current->next = head;
    return current;
}
```

You need to change the value of head to current, or your data are lost, because you start from the last head every time.
so do something like

```
if (addEMP_ID < head->EMP_ID)
{
    current->next = head;
    head =  current;
    return current;
}
```

I also notice that you read a double (Salary) as a decimal integer.
And what's the porpuese of temptr?
You also DON'T NEED TO CAST A MALLOC!